# Silverlight Remove Popup Control from Visual Tree

Tags: silverlight, popup

I have a silverlight application, with a control (kind of tooltip) inside a popup, and want to remove this popup in certain case.

In silverlight spy I see that this popup is not a child element of the rootvisual, but appears at the same level.

How can I remove this Popup?

Thanks

Comment: post your code or whatever your have now!

Comment: I don't have any code to implement this - I didn't find a way to access this popup and remove it from the visual tree.

Comment: post your xaml atleast!

Comment: it's not my xaml either... I am using Silverlight.Controls.ToolTip, and it's sometimes stayed stuck on the screen. I want to remove this popup. i uploaded an image of the visual tree here - [link](http://img42.com/ZvlEg) , please see (it will soon be unavailable, so...)

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I managed to solve this issue, and it was fairly easy at last.

This is the code I used:

```
        var popups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups();
        foreach (Popup pop in popups)
        {
            if (pop != null && pop.Child is ToolTip)
            {
                ((ToolTip)pop.Child).IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
```